# Last step in proof of Green's Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In the last step of Greene's theorem in one of the proofs I'm reading, the following is written in the last step:

$ \int_{b}^{d} (Q(c,y) - Q(a,y)) dy) - \int_{a}^c (P(x,d) - P(x,b)) dx = \int_{\gamma} Q dy + P dx $

The rectangular  region is defined as

```
                        a,d             c,d

                        a,b             c,b
```

and after the equation above, the statement is: "The last step follows by parameterizing the given line segements and keeping track of the orientation as in the first paragraph.".

The first paragraph states:  "We assume that $\gamma$ is the boundary of the rectangle $\Omega$, with vertices at $(a,b), (c,b), (c,d), (a,d)$. Since $\gamma$ is positively oriented , the x variables increases from $a$ to $c$ when $y = b$and decreases from $c$ to $a$ when $y = d$. Similarly, the $y$ variable increases from $b$ to $d$ when $x = c$and decreases from $d$ to $b$ when $x = a$.".

So, my question is how they get the equality given the the various statements ? It seems to me like a region ( an area ) is being equated with a line integral and I'm not clear on why that is true. Thanks a lot for any wisdom or references.

Oh, I realize that this isn't a complex analysis question but if I have any hope of understanding complex integration then I figured I better understand this and I've had much more success asking questions on this tag compared to the calculus tag. So, that's why I put it here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first i want to correct you, for "greene's theorem", it is Green's Theorem.

The secret to success is to write the things you need. Let's parameterize $\partial D$.

$\partial D = C_1\cup C_2\cup C_3\cup C_4$ , where $C_1$ is the segment between $(a,b)$ and $(a,d)$. Therefore, to keep it simple, $C_2$ joins $(a,d)$ with $(c,d)$ and so on.

Now, using linearity, consider the double integral.

$\displaystyle-\iint\limits_D{\partial P\over\partial y}\,\mathrm dA = -\int_a^c\int_b^d{\partial P\over\partial y}\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx = -\int_a^cP(x,d)-P(x,b)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^cP(x,b)-P(x,d)\,\mathrm dx$

Let's parameterize the segments:

$\alpha_1:[t,~b]$ with parameter $t:a\leq t\leq c$
$\alpha_2:[c,~t]$ with parameter $t:b\leq t\leq d$
$\alpha_3:[t,~d]$ with parameter $t:c\leq t\leq a$
$\alpha_4:[a,~t]$ with parameter $t:d\leq t\leq b$

Now, take into account the fact that you are taking a line integral of the vector field $F=[P,0]$. Therefore, you can see that evaluating the line integral at the segments $C_2$ and $C_4$ will give you zero, because the cross product of F with each of these parameterizations will give you zero.

Then we will have

$\displaystyle\oint_{\partial D}P\,\mathrm dx=\int_{C_1}F\cdot\mathrm d\alpha+\int_{C_3}F\cdot\mathrm d\alpha$

Evaluating the line integral in $C_1$ gives us

$\displaystyle\int_a^c[P(t,b),0]\cdot[1,0]\,\mathrm dt=\int_a^cP(t,b)\,\mathrm dt$

and doing the same evaluation in $C_3$ yields us

$\displaystyle\int_c^a[P(t,d),0]\cdot[1,0]\,\mathrm dt=\int_c^aP(t,d)\,\mathrm dt=-\int_a^cP(t,d)\,\mathrm dt$

In order to clearly see the equality, you must work by definition.

Comment: thanks danieltatis. my bad for spelling. thanks for wisdom. I will print out, make sure I understand and then put a check next to the answer.

Comment: that was an amazing answer. thank you.

Comment: No it's not an amazing answer. I suggest you read the proof for Type 1 Regions, in Apostol's Calculus (Volume 2).